# What is the best paid tool to migrate products, customers and orders from Magento 2.4.2 to Magento 2.4.5?

Tags: migration, data-migration

We have 2302 products, 4520 orders and 5389 customers I need to move from our Magento 2.4.2-p1 to Magento 2.4.5-p1.

I used the Export/Import and that only moved 1568 products out of 2302 (I get Errors when doing it). I used the Magento Migration Tool previously (when moving from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.4.2-p1) and that created many problems for us so I am wary of using a tool but if someone could recommend a tool or service that works well?

Answer (score 2):

Why would you migrate to another version? I would suggest to just update the existing version to 2.4.5. Or, if you are on a live website first create a clone of the 2.4.2 including database and upgrade from there. If you insist on migrating, we use the Firebear improved import/export extension for our imports and exports. It's a useful extension for a lot of jobs. As said, I would go for the first option (just update the existing installation).

Update:
You might want as solution like Firebear because you might find it useful for other tasks as well. In that case it might be a good investment. I heard several customers in the past using paid services without any real succes-story there. I would limit your expectations there. Especially for harder projects like yours. Also for 'an expert' it might take a lot of time. I have done quite a few migrations myself (also from 1.9 to 2.4.5) and it's never a easy process because of all extensions.

In general I would advise you to use your existing install, because it already contains all products, orders and customers. Export them and start from there. Make sure your new install has the proper attributes available. If this does not work, the data might be so bad that also other forms of import/export or migration would not work. In both cases the existing data should be ok to get this working.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have taken a look and the cost for Firebear is $599.00. I would assume if I hired a company that specialises in migrations, the job may be around the same amount? I mean it will probably be just a one-off. The reason I'm trying to set up on Magento 2.4.5-p1 fresh is because our Magento 2.4.2p-1 is messed up beyond repair (too many problems with the remnants of the One-step-checkout from Amasty, payment problems etc. and some issues which came about by using the official Magento Migration Tool to migrate data from Magento 1.9.x)

Comment: Well if you have this kind of issue there will be a cost to upgrade the magento version and fix the issues, upgrade or new magento it will be the same. Anton suggestion makes more sense; migrating products to a new magento isn't the way to go.  You need to make a proper update of the version and fix the issue one by one. I'm not sure about the prices but I doubts that 600$ will do it for an upgrade. Though the 600ù solution you are thinking about isn't a good solution i think cause it will increase your dev time after by adding all the synchronisation and migration issues...No shortcut there.